# How to render text on an 3d Object?

Tags: unity, text

I want to render text on an 3d object. I'm trying to simulate a digital signage LED panel.

My lcd Panel has a material and a texture.

How can I do ?

Using 3d Text ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Solved: using TextMesh component !

Comment: If you're able to answer your question immediately after asking it, it might not have needed to be asked here in the first place. ;) But if your goal is to pass along your solution for other developers to learn from, then this answer could be improved by going into more detail about how you used TextMesh to solve your problem - maybe illustrated with examples of your setup and the results.